# Not able to pass emitted event from child to parent component

Tags: typescript, event-handling, angular-directive, angular12, angular-event-emitter

I am trying to show a pop-up (modal) if user enters any text in textboxes and click on a subheader showing him a confirmation modal.

I have done the modal part like on click of subheader. But wanted to show it only when user enters some text and click in that subheader.

For that I am using (keyup) in the html to pass it as the values as a eventEmitter.

Below is my **search.component.html** this is **child component**

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let field of searchFields" class="column">
      <app-form-field [field]="field" [form]="form" (keyup)="sendToParent(this.form.value)"></app-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <app-button [type]="this.button.RESET"></app-button>
      <app-button [type]="this.button.SEARCH"></app-button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is my **search.component.ts**  code

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonType } from '../../shared/button/button-type';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

import { FormBase } from '../../shared/form/models/form-base';
import { FormService } from '../../services/form.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-form',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../landing.component.scss'],
  providers: [FormService]
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() searchFields:FormBase<string>[] | null = [];
  @Output() outputToParent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  form:FormGroup;
  value:string="Apples";

  public get button():typeof ButtonType {
    return ButtonType;
  };

  constructor(private formService:FormService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formService.toFormGroup(this.searchFields as FormBase<string>[]);
  }

  sendToParent(value: any) {
    console.log("Emmitted event from search+++", value);
    this.outputToParent.emit(value);
  }
}
```

On the console I can see if I enter any text in the textboxes it is being printed. So I am thinking it is able to emit the values that I entered.

But in the parent component I am trying to get the emitted values but the **emitted event method** is not getting called.

this is my **nav.component.ts** code which I am treating it as my **parent** component.

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {ModalComponent} from "../components/modal/modal.component";
import {MatDialog, MatDialogConfig} from "@angular/material/dialog";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})

export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  recievedFromChild:string="empty";

  constructor(private router:Router,
              public matDialog: MatDialog) {
  }
  // $event: any;
  ngOnInit():void {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  }

  openLogoutModal() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.id = 'modal-component';
    dialogConfig.data = {
      name: 'Ok',
      title: 'Do you want to reload/refresh the screen. Entered Search data or Results would be Lost" and an OK & CANCEL button',
      actionButtonText: 'Ok'
    };
    const modalDialog = this.matDialog.open(ModalComponent, dialogConfig);
  }

  GetOutputVal($event: any) {
    console.log("Parent++++", this.recievedFromChild);
    this.recievedFromChild = $event;
  }

}
```

html code for **nav.component.html**

```
<div class="navigation-container">
  <div class="center-top flex-container">
    <a id="nav-system-parameters" class="left navigation" routerLink="/search" (click)="openLogoutModal()">System Parameters</a>
    <a id="nav-search" class="right navigation" routerLink="/search">Search</a>
  </div>
</div>
<app-landing-form (outputToParent)="GetOutputVal($event)"></app-landing-form>
```

My expectation is to get call to **GetOutputVal** method once the event is emitted from child component. But it is not getting called.

this is my **app.component.html** code

```
<div class="title-container">
  <div class="app-title flex-container">
    <h1 id="main-title" class="center-top">Main title</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <hr class="line">
  </div>
</div>
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have also tried the exact same way as mentioned in

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8app2?file=src%2Fapp%2FParent%2Fparent.component.html
```

but i am not success, not sure what else is going wrong. Any leads on the exact issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetOutputVal($event: any) {
  console.log("Parent++++", this.recievedFromChild);
  this.recievedFromChild = $event;
}
```

should be:

```
GetOutputVal($event: any) {
  this.recievedFromChild = $event;
  console.log("Parent++++", this.recievedFromChild);
}
```

Weird that GetOutputVal has an uppercase G. Also weird that recieved is mispelt should be received. But these should not stop your code working. Always worth restarting Angular dev server in case its a caching issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have written a mock code which is why you see some mistakes, but  the main issue is **GetOutputVal** method itself is not getting called. Not sure why....